# Zurb Foundation 4 - Clearing - binding an event to open.

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I'm having problems binding an event to when the Foundation "Clearing" function is opened.
Basically, when someone clicks on an image in the clearing ul, it should fire a javascript.  But,  can't get it to work.

Here's my content:

```
<div id="tourImages">
  <ul data-clearing>
   <li><a href="/img/someimage.jpg"><img src="/img/someimage-thumb.jpg"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then, in my javascript, I'm using the following:
(note: I'm using "jQuery" instead of "$" because this is a Wordpress site.)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(document).foundation();

  jQuery("div#tourImages").on("opened.clearing.fndtn", function(event, alert) {
    // do javascript or jquery here. 
  });

});
```

Comment: Does Anybody know how to do this?  If what I'm doing is correct or not?